# Unknown column issue with mysql alias

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out why i am getting an unknown column when the column is an alias that was created. Any help would be great.

code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.id, 
    ((SUM(c.width_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.width_inches))) AS width, 
    ((SUM(c.height_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.height_inches))) AS height 
    FROM carpets AS c 
    WHERE c.active = '1' 
    AND (width BETWEEN '0' AND '275') 
    AND (height BETWEEN '0' AND '599') 
    ORDER BY c.item_no
```

error:

> Unknown column 'width' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot access the alias directly by name.

One solution is to wrap the query with the aliases in a subquery, and then refer to the alias names in an outer query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM 
    (
     SELECT c.id, 
          ((SUM(c.width_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.width_inches))) AS width, 
          ((SUM(c.height_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.height_inches))) AS height
     FROM carpets AS c 
     WHERE c.active = '1'
    ) sub
WHERE (sub.width BETWEEN '0' AND '275') 
AND   (sub.height BETWEEN '0' AND '599') 
ORDER BY sub.item_no
```

Comment: that got rid of the error however it now shows no results when it should show 1046 results....any ideas

Comment: @Nate - Does the inner query retrieve any results? And if so, are the width and height within the bounds you are checking for?

Comment: @Nate - I also moved the `DISTINCT` up to the outer `SELECT`. That could have been causing problems as well.

Comment: just 1 bu the result doesn't make sense the "width" and "height" are really big numbers

Comment: fixed that but now there is no results just comes back empty

Answer (score 9):

You can use aliases in the order by clause, but you can't use aliases in the where or group by clause. Either you repeat the expression or you can use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use your "width" alias in your "width between .. and .."; you need to repeat the raw calculation, sadly. Same for "height". So, the following should work:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT c.id, 
         ((SUM(c.width_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.width_inches))) AS width, 
         ((SUM(c.height_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.height_inches))) AS height 
FROM     carpets AS c 
WHERE    c.active = '1' 
AND      (((SUM(c.width_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.width_inches))) BETWEEN '0' AND '275') 
AND      (((SUM(c.height_feet)*12)+(SUM(c.height_inches))) BETWEEN '0' AND '599') 
ORDER BY c.item_no
```

Comment: when trying that i get the error: Invalid use of group function