# SQL if number of hires leaves 1 left (Use column alias in where clause)

Tags: mysql

I am having a small issue with a simple SQL statement.

I need to find out if I have 7 copies of a movie in the movie table and 6 people have rented it out, I need to see that I only have 1 copy left (I need to do this all through the SQL query). I know normally I would do it using PHP and just takeaway the number hired from the total number of copies, but sadly my college wants me to do it the other way.

```
SELECT *,  
COUNT(distinct hire.movie_id) AS num_orders
FROM `movie`
INNER JOIN hire ON hire.movie_id = movie.id
WHERE num_orders < movie.no_copies;
```

When I run this I get the following issue `#1054 - Unknown column 'num_orders' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown column issue with mysql alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037122/unknown-column-issue-with-mysql-alias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an alias in a where predicate - you either need to repeat the predicate, wrap the query in a derived table before filtering on the alias, or you can also use `HAVING` as per below (in MySql, at least).

I don't see the need for `DISTINCT h.movie_id` (since you want to count the rentals? - possibly `DISTINCT h.hireid` ?), and it seems you will need to group by the movies to count the number of rentals.

How about:

```
SELECT m.id, m.no_copies, COUNT(h.movie_id) AS num_rentals
FROM `movie` m
INNER JOIN hire h ON h.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id, m.no_copies
HAVING num_rentals < m.no_copies;
```